# How can I rotate an Object around the camera (angle)?

Tags: unity-game-engine

What I want to do is spawn an object in front of the camera and the side I am looking at. When I change the rotation of the camera (looking at a different side), the object is still spawned at the same position. How can I change this (that the Object also changes his angle)?

```
public void Create(Object myPrefab)
{
    Vector3 instantGO = Camera.main.transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, 7);
    Instantiate(myPrefab, instantGO, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `transform.forward` - this gives a position relative to the transform e.g. `Camera.main.transform.position + (Camera.main.transform.forward * 5)` for 5m in front of the cam.

Comment: Great, will post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform.forward` - this gives a position relative to the transform e.g. `Camera.main.transform.position + (Camera.main.transform.forward * 5)` for 5m in front of the cam.

The `forward` and `left` properties return a vector of magnitude one, pointing in the direction the transform is facing, or to it's left. You can use `-forward` and `-left` to align backwards or to the right. Add this to the position of the object and multiply it to give a position a number of units away. In recent versions of Unity you also have `transform... up, down, right` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use this [Instantiate](https://Instantiate(Object%20original,%20Vector3%20position,%20Quaternion%20rotation,%20Transform%20parent);) variant:

```
Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Transform parent);
```

And pass the Camera transform as the parent parameter. This will make the new object a child of the camera and thus always moves/rotates with the camera.